# Prevent flow from proceeding until button is pressed in Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, constructor

I want to create a simple swing form that will receive input from the user. The tricky part is that I would like the constructor of the form to stop the flow of the program until the user hits the button. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, please enter your name");
    String name = new Input().getText();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + name);
}
```

I would like for the flow to be stopped inside the constructor of Input before it calls the getText() method until the user hits the button that call an ActionListener on the Swing form that the constructor produces.

Here is the code for Input:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Input extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String text;
private JPanel panel;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JButton button;

public Input(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(3,3));
    textArea = new JTextArea(5,10);
    button = new JButton("submit");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            setText(textArea.getText());

        }
    });     
    panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    textArea.setSize(1500, 1500);
    add(panel);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public synchronized String getText() {
    while(text==null)
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    try {

        return text;
    } finally {
        dispose();
    }
}

public synchronized void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    notifyAll();
}

}
```

My feeling is that what needs to be done is for the constructor to somehow get a hold of the  lock for the thread that the main is running on and only release it when the setText() method is called from the ActionListener, but I have no clue how to do that.

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a modal dialog box; however, are you aware [JOptionPane can do this already](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try do further processing in `ActionListener`:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
   String name = textArea.getText();
   // ans so on, and then:
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + name);
}
```